# Ruby on Rails, Active Record Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, updating

working on a tutorial for Ruby on Rails. I just noticed that I had miss-spelled one of my column names when I generated my migrations. When I try to work with associations I get this error.

```
 first_page = Page.new(:name => "first page", :permalink => 'first', :position => 1)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: position
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1564:in `attributes='
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `attributes='
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412:in `initialize'
    from (irb):5:in `new'
    from (irb):5
>>
```

My question is how do I update active record with the correct spelling of the Position. I've changed it in my Schema file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix your initial migration to have the correct spelling, then run:

```
$ rake db:migrate:reset
```

This will delete your development database (and any data in it!), create an empty development db, and re-run all the defined migrations against it.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't recommend it on your production server, but on your development workstation (and especially when working through a tutorial), it's just fine.

Comment: Nope.  It deletes the database, then re-runs all the migrations, so by definition it makes the database match the result of all migrations.

Comment: You right, I was confused between `rake db:migrate:reset` and `rake db:reset`. Sorry, will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the migration feature to update your schema rather than doing that manually.

Find more info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 2):

Never edit the schema manually.  That will not make any changes to your database tables.

Simply run a new migration to rename the column:

```
rename_column :table, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
```

To answer your question "How do I update Active Record", you're being a bit unclear with your terms.  Do you mean "How do I update the database table"?  If so, the answer is either rollback your migration and fix it, or run a new migration.  Either will work, but rollbacks can cause data loss in production mode (which I assume is not your case).

To change the models you simply open the ruby file in a text editor and change it.

Answer (score 2):

If you already commit/push your migration, it is possible than other people already execute it so you are better to fix the problem with a new migration, from @Ed Haywood :

```
rename_column :table, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
```

If you do not have shared this migration, you can fix the migration instead of creating a new one. To undo the last migration

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then fix your migration and run it again `rake db:migrate`

You should **never edit your schema.rb manually**, it is updated each time you run a migration. In your case without editing it, it should be correct when you have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I rollback the migration (with rake db:rollback), fix it and run it again;